# How do you analytically describe traversing a curve in the counterclockwise direction?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, line-integrals

while I was studying Vector Calculus with Apostol book, I read this part:

> "In a completely rigorous treatment of Green’s theorem it
>   would be necessary to describe analytically what it means to traverse a closed curve in
>   the “counterclockwise direction.”

and I'd like to know where to find more information about this, or if anyone has a precise definition of an analitycal description of moving along a curve in  the counterclockwise direction,
thanks.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, will check that out.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seriously considered this question before you asked it, so these are my thoughts which may be overcomplicating things.

You could perhaps think about it in terms of a parameterization for the simple, closed curve $C$.  For instance, if your curve is parameterized by $r(t) = \langle x(t), y(t) \rangle$ and your parameterization traverses the curve in the "counterclockwise direction'' then your unit normal vector is given by $$N(t) = \frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$$ where $T(t)$ is the unit tangent vector, $$T(t) = \frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||}$$ The vector $N$ should point toward the region enclosed by $C$ (you know the curve divides the plane into an interior and exterior region by the Jordan Curve Theorem, which is never a thing I like to rely on but hey it works).  So perhaps your analytic way of determining "counterclockwise direction'' would be to say that at any time $t$, there is some $c$ which is sufficiently small for which $$ r(t) + cN(t)$$ lies in the region enclosed by $C$.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work for piecewise-defined curves with pieces that may be straight line segments (like a triangle or rectangle, for instance), so instead of using the unit normal vector as defined above, you could instead use the same idea but with $N(t)$ replaced by $RT(t)$ where $R$ is a rotation by $\pi/2$ in the counterclockwise direction.  As a matrix, $$R = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$